# How to replace characters using regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

How to replace characters '-' using regular expressions?
There some date or datetime fields in my json string and they all use character '/' as separator, such as **'2016/10/10 10:10:10'**.
now i need the date or datetime fields with this form **'2016-10-10 10:10:10'**.

For example:

```
{
 "code": "200",
 "error": "",
 "total": "10",
 "page": "1",
 "result": [
   {
     "CustomerNo": "0432215",
     "Name": "ACE-Dick/USA",
     "LastUpdatedDate": "2015/08/07 13:25:32",
     "LastUpdatedBy": "System"
   }
 ]
}
```

The text below is correct json what i want.

```
{
 "code": "200",
 "error": "",
 "total": "10",
 "page": "1",
 "result": [
   {
     "CustomerNo": "0432215",
     "Name": "ACE-Dick/USA",
     "LastUpdatedDate": "2015-08-07 13:25:32",
     "LastUpdatedBy": "System"
   }
 ]
}
```

I can find the date string using regular expresion as follow,but how can replace it?

> \d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capturing groups around the values you need to keep, and just match what you need to replace:

```
(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})
^ -1- ^ ^ -2- ^ ^ --------- 3---------- ^
```

and replace with `$1-$2-$3` where `$1` is a backreference to the value captured with Group 1, `$2` references Group 2 value, etc.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oD5mA0/1)

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/DgHZL4):

```
String s = "2016/10/10 10:10:10"; 
String rx = "(\\d{4})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(rx, "$1-$2-$3"));
```

See more on [capturing groups and backreferences here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do grouping and substitution, the syntax will vary according to the language you are using.
For grouping you can use (\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})
for substitution just use $1,$2,$3  to reference these groups while substituting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your date as a String, you can use `replaceAll()`

Example

```
yourString.replaceAll("/", "-")
```